# Iterator for custom Hashtable C#

Tags: c#, generics, iterator, hashtable

I need to provide an iterator for my custom fixed sized hashtable class, I am storing the data in
an array of linkedlist.

```
class HashTableNode<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 Key { get; set; }
    public T2 Value { get; set; }
}
class HashTableClass<T1, T2>
{
    public LinkedList<HashTableNode<T1, T2>>[] elements;
    const int defaultSize = 10000;
    
    public HashTableIterator<T1, T2> GetIterator()
    {
         return new HashTableIterator<T1, T2>(this);
    }
}

class HashTableIterator<T1, T2> 
{
    //need to implement this
}
```

For the iterator I need following functionalities:

- HasNext()    // tells if there is an element at current iterator position
- Current      // returns the value stored at current iterator position
- MoveNext()   // moves the iterator to next position

```
HashTableClass<int, string> hashtable = new HashTableClass<int, string>();
//Iterator will be used like this
HashTableIterator<int, string> iterator = hashtable.GetIterator();
while(iterator.HasNext())
{
    Console.Write(iterator.Current);
    iterator.MoveNext();
}
```

Comment: .NET has `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerator` and related generic classes that embody this concept. You shouldn't be implementing approximately the same thing but with the wrong names.

Comment: The c# equivalent to a java iterator is the enumerator. It behaves like you explained. As an added bonus you don’t need to write the class yourself and can write a function that executes part of itself every time you run it.

Comment: How to I implement the `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`for this class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET there is stadard `IEnumerable` pattern. Better to stay with this implementation. If you want to expose only values, you can do the following

```cs
public class HashTableNode<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 Key { get; set; }
    public T2 Value { get; set; }
}

public class HashTableClass<T1, T2>: IEnumerable<T2>
{
    public LinkedList<HashTableNode<T1, T2>>[] elements;
    const int defaultSize = 10000;

    public IEnumerator<T2> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return elements.SelectMany(l => l).Select(e => e.Value).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Or you can introduce methods which returns `IEnumerable`

```cs
public IEnumerable<T2> GetValues()
{
    return elements.SelectMany(l => l).Select(e => e.Value);
}
```

Or using `yield return`

```cs
public IEnumerable<T2> GetValues()
{
    foreach (var list in elements)
    {
        foreach (var node in list)
            yield return node.Value;
    }
}
```

In all cases, you can use `foreach` for your collection:

```cs
var hashTable = ...

foreach (var value in hashTable)
{
    ...
}

foreach (var value in hashTable.GetValues())
{
    ...
}
```

If you want to get "iterator" which is called `IEnumerator` in .NET, you can call `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`

```cs
using var enumerator = hashTable.GetEnumerator();
// or
using var enumerator = hashTable.GetValues().GetEnumerator();

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.Write(enumerator.Current);
}
```